# Generate harmonic polynomials for a finite group

Tags: finite-groups, invariant-theory, harmonic-functions, reflection-groups

Let $G$ be a finite group acting on a complex vector space $V$. Let $\mathcal{D}$ denote the differential operators with constant coefficients and $\mathcal{D}^{G}$ be the $G$-invariant operators. A polynomial $p$ is called harmonic if $D(p)=0$ for all $D\in\mathcal{D}^G$. Denote the set of harmonic polynomials by $H_G$. In the case of the symmetric group these polynomials are spanned by the Vandermonde determinant and all its partial derivatives. This result seems to generalize to all finite reflection groups. For a general finite group, it is clear that $H_G$ is a finite dimensional vector space, but is there a similar construction to obtain a basis?

Comment: It would help if you could tell us what the definition is of a harmonic polynomial associated to a finite group.

Comment: Also, it's important here to specify the field over which you work, since that affects notions such as "finite reflection group".   What source material are you starting with?

Comment: If I understand the Theorem on page 263 in  [Kane's](https://books.google.ca/books?id=KmL1uuiMyFUC&printsec=frontcover&hl=de&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q=harmonic&f=false) book correctly, Steinberg in fact proved that only in the case of finte reflection groups, the harmonic polynomials are generated by one polynomial and its partial derivatives?!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you need to be more clear about the word "similar". For example, the celebrated case of "diagonal harmonics" corresponding to the diagonal action of $S_n$ on $(\mathbb{C}^{2})^n$ there is some result of the same flavour, which is however much more complex (Section 4 in https://math.berkeley.edu/~mhaiman/ftp/vanishing/van.pdf), but in general, e.g. for $(\mathbb{C}^3)^n$ no such statement seems to be available.